# how to disable back button in setup build using wixtoolset on VerifyReadyDlg

Tags: wix

I am making a customize setup using wixtoolset v 3.11

On the custom diaglog CustomDlgOTP the next button pass to VerifyReadyDlg

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" Text="&amp;Next" TabSkip="no" Default="yes" Height="17" Width="56" X="236" Y="243">
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg"><![CDATA[propertyreturncode = "200"]]></Publish>
</Control>
<!-- <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomDlgOTP" Order="1"> NOT Installed </Publish> -->
```

I want user should not be able to hit back button from VerifyReadyDlg. I tried commenting but the button is still visible but with no action.
Need a way to disable the back button on VerifyReadyDlg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You disabled action bounded to that button, but didn't disable the button itself. You should rewrite `VerifyReadyDlg`, remove back button from it, and then add edited dialog to your UI **instead** of original one.

1. In Wix source code find file `VerifyReadyDlg.wxs`. Copy it to your project. In copied file rename `Dialog Id="VerifyReadyDlg"` to `Dialog Id="MyVerifyReadyDlg"`
2. In copied file delete/comment `Control Id="Back"` element.
3. In your UI (which you presented in question) add element `<DialogRef Id="MyVerifyReadyDlg" />`
4. In your UI replace all occurrences of `VerifyReadyDlg` to `MyVerifyReadyDlg` (commented part should stay commented)

Comment: Checked in the path where wix tookit SDK is installed, I don't see the file VerifyReadyDlg.wxs C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\wixui

Comment: Wix doesn't provide all source code in SDK, but it is open source. You can find it on their GitHub: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/VerifyReadyDlg.wxs